# How to add trailing zeroes to datetime as string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's an easy way to modify the following timestamps (as strings) like this:

```
2020-11-04T19:48:19.9 --> 2020-11-04T19:48:19.90
2020-11-04T19:48:20 --> 2020-11-04T19:48:20.00
```

A bit of background: I have timestamps coming from an API that typically look like this:

```
2020-11-04T19:48:19.87
```

I want to convert them to datetime, which can be done with the datetime module:

```
my_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Now %f expects 6 digits, which is easily achieved by:

```
my_ts = my_ts + '0000'
```

However, for my data the fraction-bit may be missing a trailing zero, or missing altogether, like this:

```
2020-11-04T19:48:19.9
2020-11-04T19:48:20
```

What's an easy way to achieve this?

What I currently do is this:

```
teststring = "2020-11-04T19:48:19"

if '.' not in teststring:
    fraction_length = 0
else:
    fraction_length = len(teststring.split(".",1)[1])

if fraction_length == 0:
    new_teststring = teststring + '.00'
elif fraction_length == 1:
    new_teststring = teststring + '0'
else:
    new_teststring = teststring
```

This appears to be unnecessarily complicated. There has to be a better way, doesn't it?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to keep the milliseconds, or may they be dropped all together?

Comment: I'm afraid I'll need them - there may be more than one event for a given second.

Comment: Then why did you state "I want to convert them to datetime, which can be done with the datetime module:"

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The datetime module does come with milliseconds / fractions, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
def f(string, suffix='.00', length=22):
    if len(string) == length:
        return string
    return string + suffix[-(length - len(string)):]

suite = {
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.9': '2020-11-04T19:48:19.90',
      '2020-11-04T19:48:20': '2020-11-04T19:48:20.00',
   '2020-11-04T19:48:20.00': '2020-11-04T19:48:20.00',
}

for case, expected in suite.items():
    assert f(case) == expected
```

[Check it at colab.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cS5Sa2UpETA32q3DjCTskU6sCeWQYox8?usp=sharing)

Comment: I like this approach, but this is not working if there is a 2 digit fraction. So it works for 2020-11-04T19:48:19.9 and 2020-11-04T19:48:20, but not for 2020-11-04T19:48:19.87. This is because mystr[-0:] returns the entire string, instead of an empty string.

Comment: @Sebastian ok can just return `string` if it already has a `len` equal to `length`.

Answer (score 2):

try using the dateutil library

as an example:

```
from dateutil import parser
dt1 = ['2020-11-04T19:48:19.9', '2020-11-04T19:48:20', '2020-11-04T19:48', '2020-11-04T19:48:20.01']

for dt in dt1:
    print(parser.parse(dt))
```

yields:

```
2020-11-04 19:48:19.900000
2020-11-04 19:48:20
2020-11-04 19:48:00
2020-11-04 19:48:20.010000
```

Comment: @S3DEV I am not sure I follow you?  Can you explain

Comment: I just corrected the formatting, it wasn't apparent when I posted the first time.  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: That's a great answer @itprorh66 and a helpful library I didn't now about. As I need my datetimes to stay strings that's not the right answer for me though.

Comment: Then why did you state "I want to convert them to datetime, which can be done with the datetime module"

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to boil down into needing to handle the cases where there's no decimal point or there is but there are no digits following it — otherwise `strptime()` can handle it.

The code below uses a regular expression to determine which of these two cases has occurred to modify the timestamps string accordingly when necessary.

```
import datetime
import re

tests = (
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19',
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.',
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.9',
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.90',
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.900',
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.90000',
    '2020-11-04T19:48:19.900000',
)

regex = re.compile(r'(\.\d*)')

for test in tests:
    try:
        my_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(test, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError:
        m = regex.search(test)
        test += '0' if m else '.0'
        my_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(test, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

    print(my_ts)
```

Output:

```
2020-11-04 19:48:19
2020-11-04 19:48:19
2020-11-04 19:48:19.900000
2020-11-04 19:48:19.900000
2020-11-04 19:48:19.900000
2020-11-04 19:48:19.900000
2020-11-04 19:48:19.900000
```